# Is there entry title control in EE3?

Tags: ee3, title, mx-title-control

I'm looking to auto-generate a title, for instance {firstname} {lastname}, like what you do in MX Title Control or Title Master for EE2. Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: How are you creating entries? Back end or Channel form?

Comment: From the Control Panel.